# Before or After?

Tags: punctuation

When you write a sentence dealing with punctuation; e.g. "My sister is 5'5" tall." If I wanted to ended the sentence at 5" does the comma or period go before or after the quotes?  Thank you for your help.  -Ella

Comment: This involves basic punctuation, and has been addressed extensively on this site.

Comment: There's a comma?

Comment: HellooOoo? I'm new here, but after doing a search on the subject I couldn't find it? I don't have the time to be looking up to see if it's been addressed extensively.  Forgive me for bothering you people, but I thought this website was intended to be of help for those who had questions. Thanx, vladkornea.

Comment: Could you actually type the alternatives rather than describe them? Thanks.

Comment: The character `"`, when used to mean "inches", is not punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

> If I wanted to ended the sentence at 5" does the comma or period go
>   before or after the quotes?

Does this mean you are thinking of saying 
**My sister is 5'5"**?

If so, do you mean by "quotes" the two marks after the second 5 (in this case, 5 inches?) - **5"**

This mark is known as a **double prime**. It should not be confused with quotation marks. It is used to indicate various units (in your case, inches):

> The double prime ( ″ ) represents inches (in), arcseconds (as), and
>   seconds (s). - *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29)*

You can only complete the sentence after you have indicated the unit. Otherwise the measurement is incomplete, leaving the sign for inches hanging sadly cut off from its sister **the single prime** (**feet**).

So the full stop (period) would come last of all:

> My sister is 5' 5".

But, have I understood the question correctly?

Comment: Yes Margana, you've understood the question correctly.  Had already found the answer elsewhere, but it's appreciated and thanx for your detailed answer anyway.  -Ella

Comment: Thank you to all who were helpful in answering my questions, but especially to Margana!  And to all the grumpies and surlies (WS2), well y'all know where you can go.  Good-bye.